# AutoHotkey Detecting PixelColor for longer then x Seconds

Tags: global-variables, global, autohotkey

I'm on version AHL_L 32Bit 1.1.05.06

I'm looking for a logical way to detect on AutoHotkey if a pixel is up for x amount of time, after 15 seconds, I'm assuming it crashed and we're gonna refresh.

My current code is like this:

```
CrashCheck:
if stuckinbonus = 0x1D001A
{

    if(FoundCrash = 0) {   
     FirstFound := A_Tickcount
     FoundCrash = 1
        } else {
 CrashCheckTime := A_Tickcount - FirstFound
    }




if(CrashCheckTime >= 15000){
SetTimer,CrashCheck,off
 MsgBox,Refreshing page (Pseudo Code)
}
}
return
```

I've tried putting the variables as global like this at the start of the script, but I'm running into issues with the CrashCheckTime just being 0 :/ Any ideas?

```
Global FoundCrash := ""
Global FirstFound := "0"
Global CrashCheckTime:= ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this do the job?

```
#SingleInstance Force
#installKeybdHook
#Persistent
SetTimer, CrashCheck, 1000 ; run CrashCheck every second
MyAlert := 0
Return

CrashCheck:
PixelGetColor, Color, 100, 100
If (Color = 0x1D001A)
{
    MyAlert++
}
Else
{
    MyAlert := 0
}
If (MyAlert > 15)
{
    MyAlert := 0
    Refresh Page
}
Return
```

With regard to your own code. Could it be that you do not set the `FoundCrash := 0` before running the CrashCheck? This way you will NEVER get true for the `If (FoundCrash = 0)` and thus ALWAYS jump to the `Else` choise.

Example:

```
#SingleInstance Force
#installKeybdHook
#Persistent
;FoundCrash := 0 ; Script fails when this line is commented out!
stuckinbonus = 0x1D001A

!t:: ; [Alt]+t to simulate CrashCheck
If (stuckinbonus = 0x1D001A)
{
    If (FoundCrash = 0)
    {   
        SoundBeep, 500, 500 ;(Low beep)
                FirstFound := A_Tickcount
        FoundCrash := 1
    }
    Else
    {
        SoundBeep, 1500, 500 ;(High beep)
        CrashCheckTime := A_Tickcount - FirstFound
    }
    If (CrashCheckTime >= 15000)
    {
    ;SetTimer,CrashCheck,off
    FoundCrash := 0
    MsgBox,Refreshing page (Pseudo Code)
    }
}
Return
```

I suggest you run this in debug mode inside SciTE4AutoHotKey, to see which branches are taken and what the variable values are during step by step execution.

Comment: Could you provide some feedback? I know that my solution is different from yours. Or is it that you only wanted to know why some variables stayed empty?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little function that loops, waits, and keeps looping until it sees the desired pixel colour at the desired coordinates.  Maybe this is helpful?

```
;This function checks the Pixel at the provided coordinates and waits until the colour matches the provided parameter 
WaitForLoad(PixelColorX,PixelColorY,PixelColorValue)
{
CycleCount = 0
  PixelGetColor SearchPixel, PixelColorX, PixelColorY
  ;msgbox "Found Pixel %SearchPixel% at %PixelColorX%, %PixelColorY%, Looking for %PixelColorValue%" ;DEBUGG ASSISTANT
  While (SearchPixel != PixelColorValue)
          {
    CycleCount = CycleCount + 1
    sleep 100
    ; Tooltip Waiting to detect pixels HERE!, PixelColorX, PixelColorY     ; Doesn't work
    PixelGetColor SearchPixel, PixelColorX, PixelColorY
  }
  sleep 500
;Debug
;msgbox Exiting Function with %PixelColorValue% at %PixelColorX%, %PixelColorY% after %CycleCount% Cycles.
SearchPixel = 0
PixelColorValue = 1
```